# Cauchy product when indices don't match

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometric-series, cauchy-product

I want to find the first $4$ coefficients of the Maclaurin series of $\tan(z)$ by multiplying by $\cos(z)$ and using a Cauchy product.

Letting $\tan(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty c_kz^k$ and multiplying by $\cos(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k!}z^{2k}$ gives 
$$\sin(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty c_kz^k \cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k!}z^{2k}$$
and the coefficients can be equated to the series representation of $\sin(z)$ to find $c_0,\ldots,c_4$.

However, I am not sure how to take the Cauchy product of this since the indices of $z$ don't match. Is there some manipulation that can be done to the limits of the sums or the powers of $z$ to let this product fit the definition of a Cauchy product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted the indices to match, you can use this series instead:
$$\cos(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2} \right)}{k!}x^k$$